# Did google ported android toolchain from Codesourcery?

Tags: android, arm, toolchain

whether toolchain provided in android source code for ARM is based on CodeSourcery toolchain ?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a custom gcc build with some extra patches.

`gcc -v` tells how it was built, and that should be enough to answer your question. However you can not be sure about which patches they have on their gcc copy, and some of the patches might be originated from CodeSourcery.

> $arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v
>
> Using built-in specs.
>
> COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/lto-wrapper
>
> Target: arm-linux-androideabi
>
> Configured with: /tmp/AOSP-toolchain/build/../gcc/gcc-4.7/configure
>   --prefix=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.22 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.7 --with-gdb-version=7.3.x --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/toolchain-build-linux/prefix/include/c++/4.7
>   --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --disable-bootstrap --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=0.17.0 --with-ppl-version=1.0 --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> gcc version 4.7 (GCC)